# Updating UITableView with dynamic data from a url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list view controller which has a table that gets its data from Yelp. I have a separate class named "YelpObject.h/m"  which does all the job of collecting the Yelp data from the Yelp API. I also have made the YelpObject a singleton. I initialize the singleton in the ListViewController's init method.

```
-(id)initWithPlace:(NSString*)city{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        [self setCityName:city];
        [[YelpObject sharedYelpObject] initializeYelpWithLocation:city term:@"Hotels"];
        [[YelpObject sharedYelpObject] makeConnectionsToYelp];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now in the following method:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return [[[YelpObject sharedYelpObject] names] count];
}
```

names is a NSMutableArray which has the top 20 hotel names from the Yelp API. When I try to print the content of names from within "YelpObject.m", it has the desired data.

But the problem here is that by the time the "makeConnectionsToYelp" function gets its data, the above method & all the table data-source methods are called. This makes the table to always display zero rows.

I don't know how to make sure that the table data source methods are called only after the method call of

```
[[YelpObject sharedYelpObject] makeConnectionsToYelp];
```

returns.

I don't know if callback methods can help here. I am a newbie to iOS programming and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
-(id)initWithPlace:(NSString*)city{
self=[super init];
if(self){
    [self setCityName:city];
    [[YelpObject sharedYelpObject] initializeYelpWithLocation:city term:@"Hotels"];
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
    {
     [[YelpObject sharedYelpObject] makeConnectionsToYelp];
     //NSLog data returned to check.
     //may be you can add a activity indicator to show loading.
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    //reload your table view here.
    [tableview reloadData];
    //remove activity indicator if added.
    });
    }); 
return self;
```

}

Comment: Please post the code where you get zero count. Whatever I have done would first get data and then again will reload your tableView.